# How to change Azure AD (Entra ID) App registration redirect url with python

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have create an azure AD app for website login, now login function is work,but im wonder how can i change redirect URL with python, because i want to assign different URL due to different conditions.

And if i use azure cli  with comand `az ad app show --id <Client_Id>` i can see app's details, but i cant get the same result with python code...

```
`from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac.models import Application
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)
graph_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credential, tenant_id)
app_info = graph_client.applications.get(client_id)
print(f"Application ID: {app_info.app_id}")
print(f"Display Name: {app_info.display_name}")
print(f"Reply URLs: {app_info.reply_urls}")
```

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POUTi.png)]

How to change Azure AD (Entra ID)  App registration  redirect url with python

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Azure AD application** and grant **`Application.ReadWrite.All`** API permission:

[image]

**To get the application details in python, use the below python code:**

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

def get_application_info():
    app_id = "ClientID"
    tenant_id = "TenantID"
    client_id = "ClientID"
    client_secret = "ClientSecret"
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)        
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
    endpoint = "/applications"
    select = "displayName,id,web"
    req_filter = f"appId eq '{app_id}'"
    request_url = f'{endpoint}?$select={select}&$filter={req_filter}'

    response = client.get(request_url)
    app_info = response.json()['value'][0]
    display_name = app_info['displayName']
    id = app_info['id']
    redirect_uris = app_info['web']['redirectUris']
    return display_name, app_id, redirect_uris

display_name, id, redirect_uris = get_application_info()
print(f"Display Name: {display_name}")
print(f"Application ID: {id}")
print("Redirect URIs:")
for uri in redirect_uris:
    print(uri)
```

[image]

**To update the redirect URL of the Azure AD application use the below code:**

```py
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

def update_application_redirect_uris(new_redirect_uris):
    Object_Id = "ObjectID"
    tenant_id = "TenantID"
    client_id = "ClientID"
    client_secret = "ClientSecret"
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret)        
    client = GraphClient(credential=credential)
    endpoint = f"/applications/{Object_Id}"
    request_body = {
        "web": {
            "redirectUris": new_redirect_uris
        }
    }

    response = client.patch(endpoint, json=request_body)
    return response.status_code

# update redirect URIs
new_redirect_uris = ["https://jwt.ms"]
status_code = update_application_redirect_uris(new_redirect_uris)
print(f"Status code: {status_code}")
```

[image: enter image descrip`tion here]

Redirect URI updated successfully:

[image]

Comment: really appreciate for your help!! i will try it later

Comment: can i ask one more question?   
as i get token, i want to add some custom information in token, however as i set token configuration ,it makes no difference. and also it is not really customize, for example i want to create a claim call is_good  and set value to 1 , but it seems i cant do that

Comment: What scope are you passing to generate token?

Comment: I pass openid & profile. Can i ask how wil this affect token and what can i set. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, as i try your code and change app imformation to mine's, i face an error
   app_info = response.json()['value'][0]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'value'

Comment: Did you change anything in the code and can you please attach the screenshot